# Understanding the Scope and Implications of Revelation 12:9 and 1 John 5:19 in Their Biblical Context

Tags: john, revelation, satan

How should [Revelation 12:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+12%3A9&version=LXX) and [1 John 5:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+John+5%3A19&version=LXX) be understood in their biblical context, particularly in relation to the trustworthiness of religious belief systems? Revelation 12:9, which states,

> καὶ ἐβλήθη ὁ δράκων ὁ μέγας, ὁ ὄφις ὁ ἀρχαῖος, ὁ καλούμενος Διάβολος καὶ ὁ Σατανᾶς, ὁ πλανῶν τὴν οἰκουμένην ὅλην

, suggests that "the entire inhabited earth" is misled by Satan.

Similarly, 1 John 5:19, which reads,

> οἴδαμεν ὅτι ἐκ τοῦ Θεοῦ ἐσμέν, καὶ ὁ κόσμος ὁ ὅλος ἐν τῷ πονηρῷ κεῖται

, states that "the whole world is in the power of the wicked one."

Considering these passages, a theory arises: if the whole of humanity is misled by Satan, as suggested by these scriptures, would this not imply that humanity is incapable of maintaining true religion?

How do these statements, made in their specific scriptural and historical contexts, inform our understanding of the reliability and trustworthiness of religious doctrines and teachings in light of this theory?

Comment: These same texts, taken in proper and sensible context, indicate that there is a people that are not 'of the world'. They have been saved out of it and are delivered from it. 'My little children' in John, and 'they that have not the mark of the beast' in Revelation. 'The whole world' refers to the unregenerate and unrepentant part of humanity that is not of faith and lies, still, in wickedness. Welcome to SE-BH ; please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: But I don’t understand how anyone living today is not misled. I include myself. I must be misled! I cannot sensibly include myself in with the group of chosen ones from the 1st century. Because I didn’t exist in the 1st century!

Comment: Agreed with Nigel J. ___ Just as in Jesus' day, the Roman Empire was the fleshly world government; the Kingdom of God was among (within) .

Comment: We are not misled if we repent at the words of such as John the Baptist and believe the gospel of Jesus Christ. Then do we receive eternal life, and receive the Holy Spirit who guides us into all truth and keeps us from error and delusion.

Comment: The “my little children" doesn’t include anyone living today! Everyone living today didn’t exist when Jesus said that to real people who did exist in the 1st century

Comment: Proper sensible context would be exegesis. Not eisegesis!

Comment: It was John voiced those words and Jesus had already died, risen again and ascended when he uttered them. Proving that not only in the days of Jesus were these things real and true,

Comment: _For the Lord is good; his steadfast love endures forever, and his faithfulness **to all generations**._ Psalm 100:5.

Comment: True. For the 144000. But not yet for us. Hopefully it will be true for us eventually

Comment: I look at all the trouble in the earth. 50/50 national/religion. Proving revelation 12:9 and 1john5:19 are both true. Proving All Religion is false. Proving the Bible true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150436/discussion-between-ians-and-nigel-j).

Comment: @IanS Try looking at the Gospel of John Ch.17:16 "They are not of the world, even as I am not of the world." After reading this verse and meditating on it a while, read John 17:20 "Neither pray I for these alone, but for them also which shall believe on me through their word;" I hope these two verses penned by John also quoting Jesus will help. Christians are in this world but not of it. The time started with Jesus' first coming and still continues.

Comment: Why would trust any church or religion of men?

Comment: I find just believing the Bible is most rewarding.

Comment: I find just believing the Bible is most rewarding. We shouldn’t be adding to or removing from the Bible! The Bible is very simple. The father of the human race joined with Satan in Genius! There was a chosen group of humans that where used in a symbolic drama to describe a shadow of reality. These cosen people exposed themselves as hopeless idiots. These special people where eventually dropped. All humanity is still rejected. The next special people where the chosen ones who where destined to rule as kings in the kingdom. Rome killed them all. Today all humanity are
self-righteous gentiles

Answer (score 3):

Actually, different nouns are involved in the Greek despite the English being a good translation of both.

Before dealing with these specific words, let me point out Jesus' teaching on the subject:

- John 15:19 - If you were of the world, it would love you as its own. Instead, the world hates you, because **you are not of the world**, but I have chosen you out of the world.
- John 17:14 - I have given them Your word, and the world hated them, because **they are not of the world**, even as I am not of the world.
- John 17:16 - **They are not of the world**, as I am not of the world.
- Eph 2:5, 6 - It is by grace you have been saved! And God raised us up with Christ and seated us with Him in the heavenly realms in Christ Jesus
- 1 John 2:15-17 - Do not love the world or anything in the world. If anyone loves the world, the love of the Father is not in him. For all that is in the world—the desires of the flesh, the desires of the eyes, and the pride of life—is not from the Father but from the world. The world is passing away, along with its desires; but whoever does the will of God remains forever.

Thus, the NT makes a clear distinction between the wicked "people of the world" and God's people who are "not of this world".

Thus, it is almost a truism that Satan leads the whole world astray:

> Rev 12:9 - And the great dragon was hurled down—that ancient serpent
> called the devil and Satan, the **deceiver of the whole world**. He
> was hurled to the earth, and his angels with him.

Now, notice what 1 John 5:19 actually says:

> We know that we are of God, and that the whole world is under the
> power of the evil one.

Again, there is a distinction between:

- those of God
- those under the power of the evil one, ie, the whole sinful world

God calls all sinners to repent (Luke 5:32, Mark 2:17, Matt 9:13, etc) and thus become one of those who "are not of this world", ie, those who are "strangers and exiles on the earth" (Heb 11:13) who are seeking, not the things of this world, but a heavenly country (Heb 11:14-16).

Answer (score 3):

“***So "We" doesn’t include anyone living today!***” – OP

That is a wrong statement to make. It is true that Satan deceives the whole world. But God was always careful to keep a faithful “remnant” (a small group) in all the ages.

Even the best of the best prophets of God may not be aware of them.

For example, there was a time when Elijah thought that ‘he, he alone was left’ (1 King 19:14) of the genuine people of God but God replies:

> “And I have left in Israel seven thousand, all the knees that have not
> bowed to Baal, and every mouth that has not kissed him” (1 King
> 19:18).

It is obvious that these 7000 were NOT under the influence of Satan!

Jesus prophesied:

> “I will build my church; and the gates of Hades shall not prevail
> against it” (Matt 16:18).

Gates of Hades represents destruction, death, end, perishing etc. So there will be a remnant of the true church throughout the ages until the very end of the ages!

When Jesus prayed for His disciples, He prayed:

> “And I do not pray for these alone, but for those also **who shall
> believe** on Me through their word” (John 17:20).

Even at the end of the world, the Scripture says that there will be a remnant “who keep the **commandments of God** and have the **testimony of Jesus Christ**” (Rev 12:17).

Yes, even after centuries of heated debate over “faith alone”, “faith vs. works” etc:

> “Here are the ones who keep the **commandments of God** and the
> **faith of Jesus**” (Rev 14:12).

Comment: That's true! But that raises the question, why does it say that there shall be a righteous remanent (Revelation 12:17), and yet it says that the Devil deceived the whole world? (Revelation 12:9)

Comment: It is obvious that all religions are misleading and misled. Just look at so called Gods People having over 300 fragmented versions of so called Christianity. Too many of them killing each other in war! So called brothers in the same Christianity killing each other.

Comment: It is obvious that all religions are misleading and misled. Just look at so called Gods People having over 300 fragmented versions of so called Christianity.So called brothers in the same Christianity killing each other. Reality is — they are all misleading and misled! All that “We” stuff is really silly. None of the Bible writers have spoken to us today. Because We didn’t exist when they did! 
Jesus was talking to real people who did exist! John wrote his stuff to people who really did exist. No one today existed back then! You have a mind virus which blocks you from reality

Comment: @AudraM – The Scripture says, “There is none righteous, not even one” (Rom 3:10 and others). Yet, Jesus the Lord is an exception (Heb 4:15; 7:26; John 8:46; 2 Cor 5:21; 1 Pet 2:22; 1 John 3:5). Similarly, the devil deceived the whole world, except, the Remnant, which is “not of the world” yet in the world.

Comment: @AudraM. The remaining ones would not be members of Babylon the Great or Christendom. They would have nothing but faith in the true God. They wouldn’t have the mind virus of self righteousness and specialness!

Answer (score 2):

These same texts, taken in proper and sensible context, indicate that there is a people that are not 'of the world'.

They have been saved out of it and are delivered from it. 'My little children' in John, and 'they that have not the mark of the beast' in Revelation.

'The whole world' refers to the unregenerate and unrepentant part of humanity that is not of faith and lies, still, in wickedness.

We are not misled if we repent at the words of such as John the Baptist and believe the gospel of Jesus Christ. Then do we receive eternal life, and receive the Holy Spirit who guides us into all truth and keeps us from error and delusion.

Comment: The pronouns used in historical documents such as "We" don’t apply to anyone living today! So the answer given above doesn’t really answer my original question

Comment: You used the word “context“ I understand the context. You used the word "sensible" but your answer is not sensible!

Comment: @IanS  There are multitudes of statements in the bible that are entirely open ended and not restricted to the generation in which they were uttered. _I am the resurrection, and the life: he that believeth in me, though he were dead, yet shall he live: And whosoever liveth and believeth in me shall never die. Believest thou this?_ . . . . .  for example.

Comment: Ok! I don’t see how that helps. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Answer 0 shouldn’t have a tick because it didn’t answer my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by reading the whole context from 1 John 5:13-21 NIV.

> 13 **I write these things to you who believe in the name of the Son of God so that you may know that you have eternal life.** 14 This is the confidence we have in approaching God: that if we ask anything according to his will, he hears us. 15 And if we know that he hears us—whatever we ask—we know that we have what we asked of him.
>
> 16 If you see any brother or sister commit a sin that does not lead to death, ***you should pray and God will give them life***. I refer to those whose **sin does not lead to death**. There is a **sin that leads to death**. I am not saying that you should pray about that. 17 All wrongdoing is sin, and there is sin that does not lead to death.
>
> 18 We know that anyone born of God does not continue to sin; the One who was born of God keeps them safe, and the evil one cannot harm them.
>
> 19 We know that we are children of God, and that the whole world is under the control of the evil one.
>
> 20 We know also that the Son of God has come and has given us understanding, so that we may know him who is true. And we are in him who is true by being in his Son Jesus Christ. He is the true God and eternal life.
>
> 21 Dear children, keep yourselves from idols.

1 John 5:16-17 contains two statements and one action. First of all, praying to God to give "life", "life" refers to "eternal life", which God grants according to 1 John 5:13. Therefore, the "death" mentioned in both statements signifies "eternal death"

- "**sin that does not lead to death**" refers to sins that have been forgiven by God. As stated earlier in 1 John 1:9, "**If we confess our sins**, he is faithful and just and will forgive us our sins and purify us from all unrighteousness".
- Conversely, "**sin that leads to death**" represents sins that have not been forgiven. In other words, this person has not confessed their sin.

In 1 John 5:18, "anyone born of God **does not continue to sin**", refers to those who have repented and turned away from evil acts, and they are crowned as  God's children. Despite the fallen world we inhabit, God's children are safeguarded. The Son of God Jesus Christ has the power prevails over the forces of darkness. In Him, there is eternal life (1 John 5:20).

These teachings, though written two thousands years ago, remain applicable today. The term "We" encompasses everyone living in the present. However, I refrain from using the label "Religion" to describe Christianity. Jesus did not come to establish a "Religion", He brought the Good News of Forgiveness. In our fallen world, all individuals sin, but there is a category of **sin that does not lead to death**".

Answer (score 0):

Just because the Devil has already deceived the whole world does not mean that there cannot be righteous people on this earth. We have all sinned:

Romans 3:23

> For all have sinned, and come short of the glory of God.

That doesn't mean that we cannot become righteous after the fact.

John the Revelator described true sons of God as those who purify themselves:

1 John 3:1-10

> <sup>**1**</sup> Behold, what manner of love the Father hath bestowed upon us, that
> we should be called the sons of God: therefore the world knoweth us
> not, because it knew him not. <sup>**2**</sup> Beloved, now are we the sons of God,and it doth not yet appear what we
> shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like
> him; for we shall see him as he is. <sup>**3**</sup> And every man that hath this hope in him **purifieth himself**, even as he is pure. <sup>**4**</sup> Whosoever committeth sin transgresseth also the law: for sin is the
> transgression of the law. <sup>**5**</sup> And ye know that he was manifested to take
> away our sins; and in him is no sin. <sup>**6**</sup> **Whosoever abideth in him
> sinneth not**: whosoever sinneth hath not seen him, neither known him. <sup>**7**</sup> Little children, let no man deceive you: he that doeth righteousness
> is righteous, even as he is righteous. <sup>**8**</sup> He that committeth sin is of
> the devil; for the devil sinneth from the beginning. For this purpose
> the Son of God was manifested, that he might destroy the works of the
> devil. <sup>**9**</sup> **Whosoever is born of God doth not commit sin**; for his
> seed remaineth in him: and he cannot sin, because he is born of God. <sup>**10**</sup> In this the children of God are manifest, and the children of the
> devil: whosoever doeth not righteousness is not of God, neither he
> that loveth not his brother.

Our sins can be forgiven through the sacrifice of Jesus Christ and we can become righteous.

We will never rise up to the level of God because we have sinned once and require **his** sacrifice.

Just because you **were** deceived does not mean you cannot **stop** being deceived.